# SQL Query to Oracle Database with cells as parameters

Tags: vba, oracle, excel

I'm trying to query an Oracle DB from excel. I need to pass values from cells (dates etc.) into the query, this is where I'm having trouble. Say in the below simple example the date is in cell A2

```
SELECT * 
FROM ORACLE_DB 
WHERE DATE = A2
```

I've tried following the instructions on https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd but it won't work as certain buttons are grey for me such as 'parameters' in the 'definition' tab and seemingly no amount of messing around with it will work.

Other proposed solutions don't work such as changing A2 in the above example to :

```
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A2").Value
```

I haven't yet tried writing something in VBA, but surely there's an easier way to do it? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You would use an ADODB.Command/ADODB.Parameters see https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/176936/info-visual-basic-accessing-an-oracle-database-using-ado

Answer (score 0):

```
dim vbSql$

vbSql = "SELECT * FROM ORACLE_DB WHERE DATE ='" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetX").Range("A2").Value & "';"
```